# Rails Heroku Database Population

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, heroku

After deploying an app of Heroku I am having trouble getting the database populated with some of the data I need there. I ran heroku rake db:populate and it did create the initial admin user, but failed to put the rest of the data in.

I am populating the database with files from my local disk. I suspect the problem is caused because it sees nothing in the directory listed in the sample_data.rake file, as it in on my hdd and not the server. How can I get around this?

I figure that I have to either host all the files and change the directory to the servers directory, or find a way around this. I would guess there is an easy way to move the database from my computer to heroku? I'm obviously pretty new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer but have you considering using seed data instead of loading data from your local disk ? See file `db/seeds.rb` and task `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a clean local database (i.e. just the good stuff, no silly testing data), then you could try `heroku db:push`:

> `db:push [<database_url>]` # push a local database into the app's remote database

And please remember to develop on PostgreSQL if you're going to use the Heroku shared or dedicated databases, using the same database and version (version 8.3 for shared, 9.0 for dedicated) in both your development and production environments will save you much pain, suffering, and confusion.

References:

- [How can I import my existing data to Heroku?](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/import-existing-data)
- [Import: Push to Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps#import_push_to_heroku)

Comment: What if you only want to upload a single table, or add data to an existing table?

Comment: @B Seven: `heroku help db:push` will tell you how.

Comment: Thanks mu, there isn't any way to have it issue update statements instead of blanket replacing the table is there? (Other than using psql)

Comment: @c.apolzon: I don't think so but I'm not certain. I don't think there is a full database merger in the standard tasks. You could pull a copy down, do your diffs by hand, and then send those diffs back in a migration but I can't think of anything else off the top of my head.

Comment: `heroku help db:push` is not working anymore. the updated command is 

`heroku help` or more specifically `heroku help pg`. keep going from there

Answer (score 12):

heroku commands have changed. now it should be:

```
heroku run rake db:push
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rake db:seed
```

also data from local database can be uploaded to heroku by installing taps gem and pushing data from local PostgreSQL db.

```
gem install taps
heroku db:push
```

Answer (score 3):

I setup the development db, and push it to Heroku.

```
rake db:reset
rake db:seed
heroku rake db:push
```

If you are using the default PostgreSQL, another option is

```
heroku pg:reset
heroku rake db:seed
```

I use the following in the seed.rb file:

```
require 'pathname'
RailsRoot = Pathname.new(RAILS_ROOT).expand_path

print "Loading data..."
fileData = File.read (RailsRoot + "db/data-file.csv")
```